# strlen() returning a wrong value

Tags: c, strlen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char string[100];

  printf("Input string: ");
  fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
  printf("%ld\n", strlen(string));

  return 0;
}
```

To my knowledge strlen() returns the length of a string excluding the \0 but when i input "hello" it returns a value of 6

Comment: You don't say how you input "hello", but perhaps you added a newline at the end, and your string contains `hello\n` (6 chars)? You can debug by doing something like `for (char *s=string; *s; s++) printf("%d ", *s);` to see the character codes of the individual characters.

Comment: (by the way, `%zu` is the correct printf formatting string for a value of type `size_t`, and not `%ld`).

Comment: thanks its fgets that added the newline i think

Comment: Hi Kain. A step that everyone has to take when they're learning to program is to accept that it's not "strlen that returned a wrong value" or "fgets that added the newline" but rather that it's your own code or your own understanding that's wrong and that the standard library is just doing what it's supposed to be doing. The "Pragmatic programmer" book describes this idea as "select() isn't broken" (tip #33).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fgets() function adds a '\n' character to the end of the inputted string. That is why strlen() is returning +1 value. Therefore, strlen() is not returning the wrong length, rather your inputted string has an extra character.

Or to be more precise, there is always a newline character at the end of an input string, but fgets() doesn't remove it unlike other functions such as scanf() or gets(don't use it!)

If you print the ASCII character of the last element of the string, you'll see that it is printing `10.` And 10 is the ASCII value of the newline character.

Comment: fgets() doesn't add an '\n', it just doesn't trim it from the input when there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Print the string as hexadecimal and you will see that the new line character `\n` or `0x0A` is included:

```
size_t i = 0;
for (; string[i] != 0; i++) {

    printf("string[%zu] = %02X\n", i, (unsigned char)string[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
Input string: hello
6
string[0] = 68
string[1] = 65
string[2] = 6C
string[3] = 6C
string[4] = 6F
string[5] = 0A
```

EDIT: Fixed code for not handling correctly `signed char` to `int` promotion and removed unnecessary `strlen` from loop as very well recommended by @phuclv.

Comment: This will "fail" miserably when `char` is signed and the sign bit is set. Besides calling `strlen` inside a loop is a bad idea in production code

Comment: @phuclv, thank you! Definitely better now.